# powershell script to clean up ftp user folders

Tags: powershell

we have an ftp server with 50 users, they have a main folder(as below)
and 5 sub folders. I am looking for a script that will clean the contents of the sub folders on a weekly basis. However not touch the archive folder in the sub folders and do this for all the 50 users.

C:\ftp\ftp-users
jmartin --
                jmartin-a1
                jmartin-a2
                jmartin-a3
               jmartin-a4
               jmartin-a5
               archive

Answer (score 1):

You requested Powershell so here you go. Just change the C:\Folder to wherever you need. This script will get a list of folders in the root, then a list of files/folders in those folders and delete them.

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\Folder\ | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Foreach-Object{
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item
}
```

This can be expanded. Say I have the structure

```
ROOT
-Nick
--Nick1
---myfile.txt
--Nick2
---myfile.txt
-Bob
--Bob1
---hisfile.txt
--Bob2
---hisfile.txt
```

I could use the following to delete anything in the Nick1, Nick2, Bob1, Bob2 folders (Including folders) but leave the preceding structure in place. If I wanted to remove the Bob1, Bob2, Nick1, and Nick2 folders I would use the first command (Above) that would leave only Nick and Bob folders in place.

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\Folder\ | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Foreach-Object{
    $_Get-ChildItem | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Foreach-Object{
        $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item
    }
}
```

you could compress this down to a one liner

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\Folder\ | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | Get-ChildItem | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
For /R C:\ftp\ftp-users %G IN (.) do del "%G" /q
```

remember: when you want to use it in a batch put instead of one % two of them.

```
For /R C:\ftp\ftp-users %%G IN (.) do del "%%G" /q
```

Kind regards,

maesi

Answer (score 0):

You can always try:

```
del /s /q C:\FTP\*.*
```

or delete all files in sub-dirs without Archive attribute:

```
del /s /q /a:-a C:\FTP\*.*
```

Here some info:

```
  /A            Selects files to delete based on attributes
  attributes    R  Read-only files            S  System files
                H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
                I  Not content indexed Files  L  Reparse Points
                -  Prefix meaning not
```

> It will find and delete all files in sub-directories in C:\FTP\

Add this to windows scheduler as:

```
%windir%\cmd.exe
```

with params:

```
/c del /s /q C:\FTP\*.*
```